# Line breaks in email in Docker MailDev

Tags: docker, laravel-5, html-email, laravel-blade

I am using maildev in my local development and have this code in my template.

```
@component('mail::panel')
    @component('mail::table')
        | Section | details |
        |-|-|
        | name | {{ $name }} |
        | email  | {{ $email }} |
        | content | {!! nl2br(e( $contents )) !!} |
    @endcomponent
@endcomponent
```

Now, the contents is a text area field which allows the user to have a newline or multiple lines.

[image]

My problem here is that the message `this is it` should be inline with `Thank you` not with `content`.Anyone has an idea?

Comment: It is a bit hard to see the connection between your code sample and the image you posted. Where is the `message` in the image and where is the `content` in your code?

Comment: @piscator Updated. Please see. Thanks.